# Accessing the fields of a class which getters are private

Tags: java, object, getter-setter, private-members

Say i have a class such as this:

```
public final class Identity {

    private String name;
    private String nin;
    private int age;

}
```

I want to get the values of the fields in that class, of which getters are private. So far I came up with no solution other than creating a generic *Object[]* array and storing the values of each of the fields in it. Like this:

```
public Object[] getFields() {
    fields = new Object[]{getName(), getNin(), getAge()};
    return(fields);
}
```

Is this actually a bad solution? I've read that type casts are usually a sign of bad programming, and that I should probably rethink my strategy, but I see no potential drawbacks because: I know exactly how many fields there are in my class, I know exactly at which position they will be inside the array and I exactly know the data type of each of them. For example, if i wanted to access the field *age*, I know that it will be at the position 2 of my array (*Object[2]*) and I know that it will be of the type *int*, so I will have to cast it as an *int*.

I welcome any ideas.

Note: I should mention that it's a requirement that the setters and getters of the method need to not be accessed by another interferring class, hence why they're declared as private. Furthermore, in my program, the class is implementing an interface such as this:

```
public interface Attribute {

    // Fills the fields of the class with the data the user wants to.
    void fill ( );

    void view ( );

    // Edits one or more of the fields of the class with the data the user wants to.
    void edit ( );

    String toString ( );

}
```

Which, as you can see, doesn't have any setters and getters defined. The *getFields()* method would normally be declared in the interface if it's accepted as not that bad of a solution, of course.

Comment: I think this is going to venture into opinion very quickly. The only problem I see is that by return a specific `Object[]` you're losing type-safety which is one of the strengths of Java and you're likely making it more annoying to work with the method in your other classes in the future. My solution in situations like this is to add methods to return a copy of the private data so the privacy of the data is respected. In your case (with nearly all primitives) this is as simple as returning the value (Strings are immutable in Java). Best of luck.

Comment: I don't understand how returning an array of values is better than having public getters. Using the array correctly would you to know the class anyway.

Comment: @shmosel I can't use any method that's not declared in the interface, that's why the getters can't be used. I get nothing out of declaring and using an interface if I'm gonna be using methods that aren't defined in the interface. Knowing exactly how the class is defined is not a concern to me.

Comment: What is the purpose of not exposing the getters? Whatever malicious stuff you can do with getters is present even if you return an array like that. For immutable objects or primitives, getters do not allow the caller to do anything, while mutable ones can be modified by exposing them through either method.

Comment: So cast it to the class and call the getters. Or are you saying there's some generic use for the set of fields that's agnostic to the specific structure? If so, please elaborate on that.

Comment: Actually, I would think that using reflections to retrieve the values would be better than doing this. When a class defines certains fields `private` with `private` getters and setters, it is implying that no one should know that this field existed from outside. However, this class is also implementing an interface that wants to tell the whole world all its data, which is a contradicting idea. At least when using reflections, it is clear that you are *intentionally* breaking this protection.

Comment: @shmosel "So cast it to the class and call the getters". Hmmm, I actually didn't even think of doing it like that, seems like it could be a good solution. Should also specify that I generally don't like having getters and setters as public. It's just a preference thing, I just don't like giving other unrelated classes the ability to modify the data of the fields inside my class. If I wanted to modify the data of the fields, I already have defined other methods inside the class that can do that, such as edit().

Comment: @Jai You raise a good point. I could definitely see why it would seem to be contradictory. I also don't think it's that good of an idea to keep the getters and setters as private if the only alternative to access the fields is by using reflection (other than what i posted earlier, i mean).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've left this question open for long enough. Turns out, as @shmosel pointed out, the answer was incredibly trivial. All I needed to do was to set the getters of the class as public (setters will still remain as private, the idea is that i want the fields inside the class to be viewable but not modifiable by any unrelated class) and do a cast on the class. Like this:

```
Identity identity = (Identity) attribute;
String name = identity.getName();
String nin = identity.getNin();
int age = identity.getAge();
```

That's it. Pretty trivial stuff as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it's the best design, it seems that you could use reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public MyClass {

    String getName(Identity identity) {
       return getStringFieldValue(identity, "name");
    }

    String getNin(Identity identity) {
       return getStringFieldValue(identity, "nin");
    }

    int getAge(Identity identity) {
        return getIntFieldValue(identity, "age");
    }

    String getStringFieldValue(Identity identity, String fieldName) {
       try {
           Field field = identity.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
           field.setAccessible(true);
           return (String) field.get(identity);
       } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
           return "";
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           return "";
       }
    }

    int getIntFieldValue(Identity identity, String fieldName) {
       try {
           Field field = identity.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
           field.setAccessible(true);
           return (int) field.get(identity);
       } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
           return -1;
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           return -1;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using reflection? Ouch. If it really comes to that in the end, I'd much rather change the fields to public.

Comment: I agree. Public fields would definitely be a better design than reflection.